# show/hide textarea if logged in/out?

Tags: php, authentication

Please help, i am trying to make it so that upon users or guests visiting my webpage they will see a text area which is disabled and once they've logged in they can then click to edit this text area.

I have it pretty much set up how i want it but at the moment if a user logs in the text areas are switched from the disabled one to the editable one. but then all the other text areas of the other profiles disappear and i want these to stay so the logged in user can see other users ones but not edit them?

Hope i've explained that clearly enough. Hope this is possible?

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { 
            if ($user['id'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){
 ?>                 

<textarea id="area"  rows="10" style="
    width: 456px; 
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height: 122px;
    resize: none; 
    border: hidden;"><?php echo $profile['bio'] ?> </textarea>

<?
} 
}
?>

<?php
    if (!logged_in()) {
        ?>

<textarea id="area-read" disabled="yes" style="
    width: 456px;
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height: 122px;
    resize: none; 
    border: hidden;"><?php echo $profile['bio'] ?> </textarea>
<?
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said for other profiles, the textarea disappears. That is because after the user logs in, his session is set. And only in profiles where `id` is equal to the session `user_id`, the textarea is printed. So you need to handle the else case for the `if` inside the first `if` block.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{ 
    if ($user['id'] == $_SESSION['user_id'])
    {
?>                 

    <textarea id="area"  rows="10" style="
    width: 456px; 
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height: 122px;
    resize: none; 
    border: hidden;"><?php echo $profile['bio'] ?> </textarea>

<?php
    }
    else
    {
    //Printing the text area for other users/profiles. This is what you said was missing.
?>

    <textarea id="area-read" disabled="yes" style="
    width: 456px;
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height: 122px;
    resize: none; 
    border: hidden;"><?php echo $profile['bio'] ?> </textarea>

<?php
   }
}
?>

<?php
    if (!logged_in()) 
    {
?>              
    <textarea id="area-read" disabled="yes" style="
    width: 456px;
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height: 122px;
    resize: none; 
    border: hidden;"><?php echo $profile['bio'] ?> </textarea>
<?php
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put only the  disabled="yes" in php check

```
<textarea id="area-read" <?php if(!logged_in()) { echo 'disabled="yes"'; } ?>
```

Comment: thanks but that just duplicates the editable text area upon log in and shows them both. and while it does show all the other users these are showing as editable text areas aswell :/

Answer (score 0):

Like Svetlio said only put the disabled in the check, but also extend your check so you only enable the textarea for this user and disable the others.

```
<textarea id="area-read" <?php if(!logged_in() || $_SESSION['user_id']!=$user['id']) { echo 'disabled="yes"'; } ?>
```

EDIT:

To respond to you comment, normally you would NOT be able to see the textarea twice for the logged in user, so here is the full version of what the code needs to be:

```
<textarea id="area-read" <?php if(!logged_in() || $_SESSION['user_id']!=$user['id']){ echo 'disabled="disabled"' } ?> style="
    width: 456px;
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height: 122px;
    resize: none; 
    border: hidden;"><?php echo $profile['bio'] ?> </textarea>
```

that is all you need, nothing more

Comment: Or if you don't like the single check, you can edit your last if to if(!logged_in() || $_SESSION['user_id']!=$user['id']) instead

Comment: thats great thank you it works. all the otehrs are showing as disabled now and when the user logs in he/she can edit theirs, but the only problem is the disabled text area and the editable text area are both showing for the logged in user now. is there a piece of code i could use to hide the disabled one? thank you.

Comment: I have edited the response, normally using only this code you will see just one textarea per user, and it will be disabled for the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

`disabled="disabled"` is the correct syntax for textarea.
so you should:

```
<textarea id="area-read" <?php echo ( (!logged_in() ? (" disabled='disabled' ") : ("") ) ; ?>
```